# List Template does not show up in PowerShell

Tags: list, powershell, list-template

I have about 15 List templates in the (gallery > List templates) and none of them show up when I run following script:

```
 $web.ListTemplates | ForEach{ write-host $_.Name }
```

I think that is the reason I am not able to create list based on a template that is in List Template Gallery.

Answer (score 2):

You must use the following method [SPSite.GetCustomListTemplates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.getcustomlisttemplates.aspx) to get the list templates create by end users.

[SPSite.GetCustomListTemplates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.getcustomlisttemplates.aspx)

> Returns the collection of custom list templates, which are created by
>   end users, from the specified site.

[SPWeb.ListTemplates property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.listtemplates.aspx)

> Gets the collection of all list definitions and list templates that
>   are available for creating lists on the website.

To find a specific template you can use for example

```
$web = Get-SPWeb <url of your web>
$site = $web.Site
$templateName = "<template to find>"
$listTemplate = $site.GetCustomListTemplates($SPWeb) | ? {$_.InternalName -match $templateName }
```

Comment: To get all Custom List Templates, skip line 3 & 4 and use

$listTemplate = $site.GetCustomListTemplates($web)

Answer (score 1):

In order to return the collection of custom `List Templates` the [SPSite.GetCustomListTemplates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.getcustomlisttemplates.aspx) method is intended.

### Prerequisites for custom list templates

SharePoint List must meet the following criteria to move a list by using a list template (source):

- The list must contain less than 10 megabytes (MB) of list data.
- You must be a member of a site group with the Manage Lists right on
  the source site and on the destination site. By default, the Manage
  Lists right is included in the Web Designer and Administrator site
  groups.
- The source site and the destination site must be based on the same
  site template.

Example:

Assume a scenario where source site and the destination site are be based on the different site template.

Then after uploading list templates (stp files) into List Template gallery
[image]

the method [SPSite.GetCustomListTemplates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.getcustomlisttemplates.aspx) will return only list named `SharePoint Incidents` (Custom List type)